# Stack-buffer based STL allocator?

Tags: c++, stl, stack, allocator

I was wondering if it practicable to have an C++ standard library compliant `allocator` that uses a (fixed sized) buffer that lives on the stack.

Somehow, it seems this question has not been ask this way yet on SO, although it *may* have been implicitly answered elsewhere.

So basically, it *seems*, as far as my searches go, that it should be possible to create an allocator that uses a fixed size buffer. Now, on first glance, this should mean that it should *also* be possible to have an allocator that uses a fixed size buffer that "lives" on the stack, but it *does appear*, that there is no widespread such implementation around.

Let me give an example of what I mean:

```
{ ...
  char buf[512];
  typedef ...hmm?... local_allocator; // should use buf
  typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, local_allocator> lstring;
  lstring str; // string object of max. 512 char
}
```

How would this be implementable?

---

The [answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771458/improvements-for-this-c-stack-allocator) (thanks to R. Martinho Fernandes) links to a stack based allocator from the chromium sources: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/stack_container.h

However, this class seems extremely peculiar, especially since this `StackAllocator` *does not have a default ctor* -- and there I was thinking that [every allocator class needs a default ctor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/allocator/).

Comment: Why would this be desirable? Keep in mind that such an allocator would only be usable while that function is running.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Desirable? Weeeel, because it would mean no heap allocation (no gobal new called) and the buffer would be very local. I'm not going to sprinkle that thing all over my code, but I was wondering whether it's practically doable at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an allocator that uses alloca and is otherwise C++ STL compliant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082532/is-there-an-allocator-that-uses-alloca-and-is-otherwise-c-stl-compliant)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - I had seen this question. Is `alloca` the same as a simple *statically sized* stack based buffer??

Comment: This one may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354442/looking-for-c-stl-like-vector-class-but-using-stack-storage/354481#354481 Be sure to read the warnings. IMO This kind of thing brings more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I think stack based allocator will break move operations

Comment: @ggg - Only if you move out of the current scope. Not only move, it would also break good old `swap` etc. *Nothing* allocated through the stack based allocator must leave the local scope, as long as the lifetime of anything associated with the stack buffer based allocator is ended before the allocator is destroyed, everything is fine.

Comment: @MartinBa: You linked to the specs of `std::allocator`, but not the specs of what is an allocator.  One is an implementation, one is an interface.  The actual allocator _interface_ is bizarre.

Comment: @MartinBa: In the question, you say "every allocator class needs a default ctor", but that's incorrect. Allocator requirements are detailed in § 17.6.3.5 of the spec.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes stack space reserved in upper functions can be used passing down pointers. not so badly restricted. But I guess a clever use of this would only be beneficial if the memory is close to its use for cache locality. So in 'this' function or one step up, tops.

Comment: @v.oddou what people constantly forget is that the stack is not particularly special as memory regions go and that a large heap-allocated block also goes in the cache. The stack only wins for the setup, which would be a once per execution operation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, there [is a conforming Stack Allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html) from one [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant).

It works by using a fixed size buffer (via a referenced `arena` object) and falling back to the heap if too much space is requested.

This allocator doesn't have a default ctor, and since Howard says:

> I've updated this article with a new allocator that is fully C++11 conforming.

I'd say that it is not a requirement for an allocator to have a default ctor.

Comment: It cannot possibly be C++-conforming, because there is no standard-compliant way to determine whether a given pointer points inside or outside the stack buffer.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I'm not so sure (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225501/is-comparing-two-void-pointers-to-different-objects-defined-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657976/checking-if-pointer-points-within-an-array/4658065#4658065)

Comment: Hmm, so the problem is that comparison (i.e., `<` `>` `<=` `>=`) of two pointers that do not point to the same block of memory is not defined by the standard, but the stack allocator says `bool pointer_in_buffer(char* p) noexcept {return buf_ <= p && p <= buf_ + N;}`... although, come to think of it, since `std::less` yields a *total* order and not merely a *partial* order, I might have to retract my comment earlier -- using those may actually work. I forgot the ordering of those is total. In any case, though, the *current* code is not portable.

Comment: @Mehrdad - seems to pretty much sum it up, thanks for thinking about this :-)

Comment: actually, I'm starting to doubt this again. The order is total but there is no guarantee that it is strict, is there? In which case a <= b && a != b is not necessarily equivalent to a < b... which seems to imply that it is completely legal for std::less to always return false, even for two pointers already in the same array. Any idea if this is legal? If it's not legal, then why is the order not strict?

Comment: @Mehrdad - Sorry, this is way over my head. I guess you can start a new question with this :-) Even though it might be a near dupe to the aformentioned questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657976/checking-if-pointer-points-within-an-array etc.)

Comment: Sorry for commenting on a old question. I'm just curious: wouldn't allocating one byte more than requested and treating that byte as a tag to indicate if it was allocated by stack make the allocator standard conforming?

Comment: @vbstb - well that should make a good separate question now shouldnt it?

Comment: Thanks, good to know it's worth asking then...

Answer (score 30):

It's *definitely* possible to create a fully C++11/C++14 conforming stack allocator*.  But you need to consider some of the ramifications about the implementation and the semantics of stack allocation and how they interact with standard containers.

Here's a fully C++11/C++14 conforming stack allocator (also hosted on my [github](https://github.com/charles-salvia/charles/blob/master/stack_allocator.hpp)):

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template <class T, std::size_t N, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class stack_allocator
{
    public:

    typedef typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::const_pointer const_pointer;
    typedef typename Allocator::reference reference;
    typedef typename Allocator::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::difference_type difference_type;

    typedef typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::const_void_pointer const_void_pointer;
    typedef Allocator allocator_type;

    public:

    explicit stack_allocator(const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) 
        : m_allocator(alloc), m_begin(nullptr), m_end(nullptr), m_stack_pointer(nullptr)
    { }

    explicit stack_allocator(pointer buffer, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())
        : m_allocator(alloc), m_begin(buffer), m_end(buffer + N), 
            m_stack_pointer(buffer)
    { }

    template <class U>
    stack_allocator(const stack_allocator<U, N, Allocator>& other)
        : m_allocator(other.m_allocator), m_begin(other.m_begin), m_end(other.m_end),
            m_stack_pointer(other.m_stack_pointer)
    { }

    constexpr static size_type capacity()
    {
        return N;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type n, const_void_pointer hint = const_void_pointer())
    {
        if (n <= size_type(std::distance(m_stack_pointer, m_end)))
        {
            pointer result = m_stack_pointer;
            m_stack_pointer += n;
            return result;
        }

        return m_allocator.allocate(n, hint);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
    {
        if (pointer_to_internal_buffer(p))
        {
            m_stack_pointer -= n;
        }
        else m_allocator.deallocate(p, n);  
    }

    size_type max_size() const noexcept
    {
        return m_allocator.max_size();
    }

    template <class U, class... Args>
    void construct(U* p, Args&&... args)
    {
        m_allocator.construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <class U>
    void destroy(U* p)
    {
        m_allocator.destroy(p);
    }

    pointer address(reference x) const noexcept
    {
        if (pointer_to_internal_buffer(std::addressof(x)))
        {
            return std::addressof(x);
        }

        return m_allocator.address(x);
    }

    const_pointer address(const_reference x) const noexcept
    {
        if (pointer_to_internal_buffer(std::addressof(x)))
        {
            return std::addressof(x);
        }

        return m_allocator.address(x);
    }

    template <class U>
    struct rebind { typedef stack_allocator<U, N, allocator_type> other; };

    pointer buffer() const noexcept
    {
        return m_begin;
    }

    private:

    bool pointer_to_internal_buffer(const_pointer p) const
    {
        return (!(std::less<const_pointer>()(p, m_begin)) && (std::less<const_pointer>()(p, m_end)));
    }

    allocator_type m_allocator;
    pointer m_begin;
    pointer m_end;
    pointer m_stack_pointer;
};

template <class T1, std::size_t N, class Allocator, class T2>
bool operator == (const stack_allocator<T1, N, Allocator>& lhs, 
    const stack_allocator<T2, N, Allocator>& rhs) noexcept
{
    return lhs.buffer() == rhs.buffer();
}

template <class T1, std::size_t N, class Allocator, class T2>
bool operator != (const stack_allocator<T1, N, Allocator>& lhs, 
    const stack_allocator<T2, N, Allocator>& rhs) noexcept
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

This allocator uses a user-provided fixed-size buffer as an initial source of memory, and then falls back on a secondary allocator (`std::allocator<T>` by default) when it runs out of space.

**Things to consider:**

Before you just go ahead and use a stack allocator, you need to consider your allocation patterns.  Firstly, when using a memory buffer on the stack, you need to consider what exactly it *means* to allocate and deallocate memory.

The simplest method (and the method employed above) is to simply increment a stack pointer for allocations, and decrement it for deallocations.  Note that this *severely* limits how you can use the allocator in practice.  It will work fine for, say, an `std::vector` (which will allocate a single contiguous memory block) if used correctly, but will not work for say, an `std::map`, which will allocate and deallocate node objects in varying order.

If your stack allocator simply increments and decrements a stack pointer, then you'll get undefined behavior if your allocations and deallocations are not in LIFO order.  Even an `std::vector` will cause undefined behavior if it first allocates a single contiguous block from the stack, then allocates a second stack block, then deallocates the first block, which will happen every time the vector increases it's capacity to a value that is still smaller than `stack_size`.  This is why you'll need to reserve the stack size in advance.  (But see the note below regarding Howard Hinnant's implementation.)

Which brings us to the question ...

What do you *really want* from a stack allocator?

Do you actually want a general purpose allocator that will allow you to allocate and deallocate memory chunks of various sizes in varying order, (like `malloc`), except it draws from a pre-allocated stack buffer instead of calling `sbrk`?  If so, you're basically talking about implementing a general purpose allocator that maintains a free list of memory blocks somehow, only the user can provide it with a pre-existing stack buffer.  This is a much more complex project.  (And what should it do if it runs out space?  Throw `std::bad_alloc`?  Fall back on the heap?)

The above implementation assumes you want an allocator that will simply use LIFO allocation patterns and fall back on another allocator if it runs out of space.  This works fine for `std::vector`, which will always use a single contiguous buffer that can be reserved in advance.  When `std::vector` needs a larger buffer, it will allocate a larger buffer, copy (or move) the elements in the smaller buffer, and then deallocate the smaller buffer.  When the vector requests a larger buffer, the above stack_allocator implementation will simply fall back to a secondary allocator (which is `std::allocator` by default.)

So, for example:

```
const static std::size_t stack_size = 4;
int buffer[stack_size];

typedef stack_allocator<int, stack_size> allocator_type;

std::vector<int, allocator_type> vec((allocator_type(buffer))); // double parenthesis here for "most vexing parse" nonsense
vec.reserve(stack_size); // attempt to reserve space for 4 elements

std::cout << vec.capacity() << std::endl;

vec.push_back(10);
vec.push_back(20);
vec.push_back(30);
vec.push_back(40);

// Assert that the vector is actually using our stack
//
assert(
    std::equal(
        vec.begin(), 
        vec.end(), 
        buffer, 
        [](const int& v1, const int& v2) {
            return &v1 == &v2;
        }
    )
);

// Output some values in the stack, we see it is the same values we
// inserted in our vector.
//
std::cout << buffer[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << buffer[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << buffer[2] << std::endl;
std::cout << buffer[3] << std::endl;

// Attempt to push back some more values.  Since our stack allocator only has 
// room for 4 elements, we cannot satisfy the request for an 8 element buffer.  
// So, the allocator quietly falls back on using std::allocator.
//
// Alternatively, you could modify the stack_allocator implementation
// to throw std::bad_alloc
//
vec.push_back(50);
vec.push_back(60);
vec.push_back(70);
vec.push_back(80);

// Assert that we are no longer using the stack buffer
//
assert(
    !std::equal(
        vec.begin(), 
        vec.end(), 
        buffer, 
        [](const int& v1, const int& v2) {
            return &v1 == &v2;
        }
    )
);

// Print out all the values in our vector just to make sure 
// everything is sane.
//
for (auto v : vec) std::cout << v << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

See: http://ideone.com/YhMZxt

Again, this works fine for vector - but you need to ask yourself what exactly you intend to do with the stack allocator.  If you want a general purpose memory allocator that just happens to draw from a stack buffer, you're talking about a much more complex project.  A simple stack allocator, however, which merely increments and decrements a stack pointer will work for a limited set of use cases.  Note that for non-POD types, you'll need to use `std::aligned_storage<T, alignof(T)>` to create the actual stack buffer.

I'd also note that unlike [Howard Hinnant's implementation](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.h), the above implementation doesn't explicitly make a check that when you call `deallocate()`, the pointer passed in is the last block allocated.  Hinnant's implementation will simply do nothing if the pointer passed in isn't a LIFO-ordered deallocation.  This will enable you to use an `std::vector` without reserving in advance because the allocator will basically *ignore* the vector's attempt to deallocate the initial buffer.  But this also blurs the semantics of the allocator a bit, and relies on behavior that is pretty specifically bound to the way `std::vector` is known to work.  My feeling is that we may as well simply say that passing any pointer to `deallocate()` which *wasn't* returned via the **last call** to `allocate()` will result in undefined behavior and leave it at that.

*Finally - the following caveat: it seems to be [debatable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4658065/168288) whether or not the function that checks whether a pointer is within the boundaries of the stack buffer is even defined behavior by the standard.  Order-comparing two pointers from different `new`/`malloc`'d buffers is arguably implementation defined behavior (even with `std::less`), which perhaps makes it impossible to write a standards-conforming stack allocator implementation that falls back on heap allocation.  (But in practice this won't matter unless you're running a 80286 on MS-DOS.)

** Finally (really now), it's also worth noting that the word "stack" in *stack allocator* is sort of overloaded to refer both to the *source* of memory (a fixed-size stack array) and the *method* of allocation (a LIFO increment/decrement stack pointer).  When most programmers say they want a stack allocator, they're thinking about the former meaning without necessarily considering the semantics of the latter, and how these semantics restrict the use of such an allocator with standard containers.

Comment: Good answer. Wrt. the problem of pointer comparison, I once also considered this - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225501/is-comparing-two-void-pointers-to-different-objects-defined-in-c for a related question to the one you linked to.

Comment: there is an error in `void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)`. I don't think you can decrement stack_pointer like this.

Answer (score 6):

Starting in c++17 it's actually quite simple to do.
Full credit goes to the author of [the dumbest allocator](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2018/11/06/dumbest-allocator.html), as that's what this is based on.

The dumbest allocator is a monotonic bump allocator which takes a `char[]` resource as its underlying storage.  In the original version, that `char[]` is placed on the heap via `mmap`, but it's trivial to change it to point at a `char[]` on the stack.

```
template<std::size_t Size=256>                                                                                                                               
class bumping_memory_resource {                                                                                                                              
  public:                                                                                                                                                    
  char buffer[Size];                                                                                                                                         
  char* _ptr;                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                             
  explicit bumping_memory_resource()                                                                                                                         
    : _ptr(&buffer[0]) {}                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                             
  void* allocate(std::size_t size) noexcept {                                                                                                                
    auto ret = _ptr;                                                                                                                                         
    _ptr += size;                                                                                                                                            
    return ret;                                                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                             
  void deallocate(void*) noexcept {}                                                                                                                         
};
```

This allocates `Size` bytes on the stack on creation, default `256`.

```
template <typename T, typename Resource=bumping_memory_resource<256>>                                                                                        
class bumping_allocator {                                                                                                                                    
  Resource* _res;                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                             
  public:                                                                                                                                                    
  using value_type = T;                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                             
  explicit bumping_allocator(Resource& res)                                                                                                                  
    : _res(&res) {}                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                             
  bumping_allocator(const bumping_allocator&) = default;                                                                                                     
  template <typename U>                                                                                                                                      
  bumping_allocator(const bumping_allocator<U,Resource>& other)                                                                                              
    : bumping_allocator(other.resource()) {}                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                             
  Resource& resource() const { return *_res; }                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                             
  T*   allocate(std::size_t n) { return static_cast<T*>(_res->allocate(sizeof(T) * n)); }                                                                    
  void deallocate(T* ptr, std::size_t) { _res->deallocate(ptr); }                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                             
  friend bool operator==(const bumping_allocator& lhs, const bumping_allocator& rhs) {                                                                       
    return lhs._res == rhs._res;                                                                                                                             
  }                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                             
  friend bool operator!=(const bumping_allocator& lhs, const bumping_allocator& rhs) {                                                                       
    return lhs._res != rhs._res;                                                                                                                             
  }                                                                                                                                                          
};
```

And this is the actual allocator.  Note that it would be trivial to add a reset to the resource manager, letting you create a new allocator starting at the beginning of the region again.  Also could implement a ring buffer, with all the usual risks thereof.

As for when you might want something like this: I use it in embedded systems.  Embedded systems usually don't react well to heap fragmentation, so having the ability to use dynamic allocation that doesn't go on the heap is sometimes handy.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your requirements, sure if you like you can create an allocator that operates only on the stack but it would be very limited since the same stack object is not accessible from everywhere in the program as a heap object would be.

I think this article explains allocators it very well

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4079

Comment: *sure if you like you can create an allocator that operates only on the stack* - any prior art? I hate reinventing the wheel :-)

Answer (score 2):

A stack-based STL allocator is of such limited utility that I doubt you will find much prior art.  Even the simple example you cite quickly blows up if you later decide you want to copy or lengthen the initial `lstring`.

For other STL containers such as the associative ones (tree-based internally) or even `vector` and `deque` which use either a single or multiple contiguous blocks of RAM, the memory usage semantics quickly become unmanageable on the stack in almost any real-world usage.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an extremely useful practice and used in performant development, such as games, quite a bit.  To embed memory inline on the stack or within the allocation of a class structure can be critical for speed and or management of the container.

To answer your question, it comes down to the implementation of the stl container.  If the container not only instantiates but also keeps reference to your allocator as a member then you are good to go to create a fixed heap, I've found this to not always be the case as it is not part of the spec.  Otherwise it becomes problematic. One solution can be to wrap the container, vector, list, etc, with another class who contains the storage.  Then you can use an allocator to draw from that.  This could require a lot of template magickery (tm).

Comment: " an extremely useful practice and used in performant development, such as games, quite a bit" -- *citation needed* :-) ... Also your second paragraph is a bit unclear. What do you mean by "not only inst. but also keeps reference ..."?

Comment: I am a game developer and this guy's SO right! There are countless cases when a stack allocator and a container are used in conjunction..

Comment: Except that it _is_ part of the spec that every stl container with dynamic memory keeps a copy of the allocator.