# Linked list on the stack

Tags: c++, data-structures

Is there a C++ library that implements a linked list with all the memory on the stack?

Yes I know there will be an upper limit but looking for functionality to search it, add and delete items.

Comment: `std::list` with a custom allocator ?

Comment: I am being lazy am hoping that somebody has done this. I would also like to know the number of failed attempts so next time around I could increase the amount off space required

Comment: @EdHeal Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049657/stack-buffer-based-stl-allocator  and this http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.html

Comment: If it's on the stack, then I assume the number of elements is small. If the elements can be copied (or better, moved), you may find that a stack-based array is a simple and fast solution. Even though inserting or removing elements not at the end will cause other elements to be copied or moved, this cost can be smaller than you think for small numbers of elements.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Seems like an XY question, so I would like to understand what the Y is...

Comment: @MatsPetersson If it's an XY question then surely it's X we're after...

Comment: The X is that it will be in an application that needs to know the upper bound so dynamic (heap) is not an option

Comment: You can put an upper limit on heap space if you need to, or simply do not add more than _x_ elements.....??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I was also thinking of using it in a memory allocator to record things. So do not wish to use dynamic memory allocation as I will end in an infinite loop

Comment: What on earth are you talking about

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - For example to record when memory is dynamically allocated and therefore do not wish to use dynamic memory allocation during that process - as that will lead to going back around the circle.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Got a hook into the memory allocator and planning to utilise it to find our the usage of memory by a third party. Therefore do not wish to pollute the results with further dynamic memory allocations

Comment: @EdHeal: "A" "What" "A" "Why A?" "Entirely unrelated B" just never mind

Comment: You can use `alloca` to allocate memory on the stack instead of the heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so typically, when you hook/replace the memory alloocator, the method is to add X bytes (it's best if it's a multiple of the normal alignment, so 16 or 32 bytes in the common case) to the actual allocation, and in that store whatever information is required. Typically, you store a pointer to the "previous" allocation in this extra memory, so you can later on walk that list and examine for example what the caller is and produce some sort of histogram or "top 10 biggest users", or whatever it may be.

You can't really use stack for what you want, since you are (I presume) returning from the call to the allocation function before you are done with the information you need, so storing the data on the stack seems unreasonable.