# Is there a way to allow this in C++ Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

(sorry if this is a noob question)
Is there any way to allow fixed size C++ arrays in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition
(i.e int `arr[n]` where n is the size I want)
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: That's the opposite of a fixed size array.  Variable length arrays are not in the C++ standard and not supported in MSVC++.  Use new[] or `_malloca()`.

Comment: use `std::vector`

Comment: Make stack-based allocator and use `std::vector` with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049657/stack-buffer-based-stl-allocator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Variable sized arrays are not part of the C++ standard, and Visual Studio does not implement them.  Use `std::vector` instead.

If you've done measurements that *prove* that this vector allocation+deallocation is a major slowdown in your app (which I've never seen happen, ever), then consider using a [stack-based buffer allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049657/stack-buffer-based-stl-allocator) with the `std::vector`.

Comment: Well, difference is that vector would be allocated on heap. What would be more or less equivalent is std::vector with stack based allocator, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049657/stack-buffer-based-stl-allocator